# prove an identity of gamma function

Tags: gamma-function

During the process of computing Hawking radiation, I get an expression of gamma function.
$$\Gamma( x i) \Gamma(-  x i)$$

where x is a real number. Due to some physics motivation, I guess an identity:

$$\Gamma(x i)\Gamma(-i x)=\frac{\pi}{sinh(x)x}$$

And I verified the identity to be true using mathematica( at least for x to be real).

Can some one give me a proof? I am not good at special function. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the [reflection formula](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Euler's_Reflection_Formula) we have $$\Gamma(1-ix)\Gamma(ix) = \frac{\pi}{\sin{ix}}.$$
Now $\Gamma(1-ix) = -ix\Gamma(-ix)$ (one of the defining properties of $\Gamma$), and [we know that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function#Standard_analytic_expressions) $\sinh{x}=-i\sin{(ix)}$. Your result follows.